# Ethereum representation on OSI layers

Tags: networking, ethereum, go-ethereum

I need support with Ethereum Networking. A potential enterprise client is asking about the networking of Ethereum Node Peering. We have given them a lot of information about RLPx protocol and how it rides in Transport Layer being TCP based (Layer 4 of the 7 Layer OSI Model).

However, the question being asked is “Explain/Describe how the connectivity between 2 peers works across each of the 7 layers of the OSI Model”. Is any article or diagram available? We can’t find anything covering this particular question.

Comment: As the OSI model doesn't apply to anything in the real world apart from the defunct OSI protocol suite, which you aren't using, as you are using TCP/IP, it is difficult to see why you're asking. Or what.

Comment: Why is a client asking about this, and why do they care? This is the sort of theoretical question that gets asked in undergraduate networking classes.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/how-do-the-protocols-used-in-ethereum-e-g-whisper-p2p-protocol-suite-map-ont